# ef core 5 using Enumeration as composite keys

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get benefit from eshoponcontainers code to use classes derived from Enumeration class to address it like CardType.Visa. I think it's very convenient.
But when i try to set this type as composite key it doesn't work.
I use ef core 5 with .net core 5.
Please, any suggestions.

```
public class FakeEntity: BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ContractId { get; set; }
    }

public class FakeEntityLink
    {
        public FakeEntity FakeEntity { get; set; }
        public int FakeEntityId { get; set; }
        public int BillParamTypeEnumId { get; set; }

        public BillParamTypeEnum BillParamTypeEnum { get; private set; } = BillParamTypeEnum.PriceCategory;

        private FakeEntityLink() { }
        public FakeEntityLink(FakeEntity fakeEntity, BillParamTypeEnum billParamTypeEnum)
        {
            FakeEntity = fakeEntity;
            BillParamTypeEnum = billParamTypeEnum;
        }
    }

public class BillParamTypeEnum
        : Enumeration
    {
        public static BillParamTypeEnum PriceCategory => new BillParamTypeEnum(1,"PriceCategory ");
        public static BillParamTypeEnum VoltageTarifLevel => new BillParamTypeEnum(2, "VoltageTarifLevel ");
        public static BillParamTypeEnum Sign => new BillParamTypeEnum(3,"Sign ");
        public static BillParamTypeEnum VolumeCategory => new BillParamTypeEnum(4,"VolumeCategory");

        public BillParamTypeEnum(int id, string name)
            : base(id, name)
        {
        }
    }

//and in dbContext

     modelBuilder.Entity<FakeEntityLink>(entity => {
                entity.HasKey(c => new { c.FakeEntityId, c.BillParamTypeEnumId });
                entity.HasOne(link => link.FakeEntity).WithMany();
                entity.HasOne(link => link.BillParamTypeEnum).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p=>p.BillParamTypeEnumId);

            }
                );

// code in controller
var fe =_db.FakeEntities.Find(1);
            _db.FakeEntityLinks.Add(new FakeEntityLink(fe, BillParamTypeEnum.VoltageTarifLevel));
            _db.SaveChanges(); // throws SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'BillParamTypeEnum' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Comment: as a workaround i can use enum instead of class derived from Enumeration and it works. I add needed attributes to enum to add additional data

Comment: this `BillParamTypeEnum` is configured as an entity type with Identity column of `id` (which can be a default convention applied by EFCore). Here I think you're the one who manages its Id (playing as role of the enum value as well), so the explicit value is always provided from the client side (not auto-gen by the db server). You can try turning off the value generation by configuring it like this `modelBuilder.Entity<BillParamTypeEnum>().Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever()`

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

Comment: yes, that's what you have to do, you should have understood it first and designed it correctly, otherwise you would have to carefully do some things manually to fix the issue. Here I think your DB is just at a very initial stage, so it's acceptable (and not very risky to do).